# Cannot get the right route with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I cannot get the right route with ajax call

In my view I have 2 html button created with php

```
<?php if ($comment_exist == null): ?>    
   <p><input type ="button" id = "sb" value="I Comment"></p>
<?php else: ?>              
   <p><input type ="button" id = "sb2" value="I Cancel my Comment"></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

My jquery script contains the following

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
         $("#sb").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "comment/create",
               success: function(data) {
                  $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
           }
           });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

I got the following  address

```
localhost/mysite/index.php/post/comment/create
```

instead of

```
localhost/mysite/index.php/comment/create
```

I must say that my view where I have buttons is launched by the post controller
and I want to call the create view  of the comment controller. And I'm using Yii framework

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: change the url to `"/index.php/comment/create"` or if you configure your htaccess file, you would do `"/comment/create"`

Answer (score 1):

I have founded  in the following way

I replace the url line  by this

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>"
```

Thank you for your help.

But I have another problem now, I'll post another question

Comment: Upvote for finding your own solution, and for posting back the solution.